# Serverless deployment serverless-plugin-split-stacks plugin doesn't decrease root resources in any configuration

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless

When changing the configuration for the [serverless-plugin-split-stacks](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks) plugin, the number of resources in the root stack stays the same. Since CloudFormation has a limit of maximum 500 resources, I need a way that can decrease it.

When splitting with the following configuration:

```
splitStacks:
  nestedStackCount: 20
  perFunction: false
  perType: false
  perGroupFunction: true
```

The result is the following *(numbers are just examples, the production environment is above 500)*:

```
Summary: 462 resources migrated into 20 nested stacks
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ (root): 301
```

When splitting with a higher `nestedStackCount`, the root will just have that much more resources in it. When splitting with `perFunction: true`, again, the number of resources just grows with the amount of new substacks:

```
Summary: 462 resources migrated into 150 nested stacks
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ (root): 431
```

Is there a way/configuration to decrease the number of resources in root so I can deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if this is too late but I believe you have to change the name of existing lambda functions to split them across stacks, as this plugin does not technically work with existing resources.

> Here is the tricky part. The plugin doesn't work with existing resources. You can force the migration of an existing resource to a new stack if you use a custom migration with force: true but it will delete the resource and recreate it. It might create conflicts in CloudFormation or issues with IAM. This is not a good idea for production environments.

> If you have existing Lambdas, you need to rename them to follow the new structure. The easiest way is to suffix their names with an underscore. For example, if you had a Lambda named myFunction, you can rename it to myFunction_. You use any other suffix you like honestly, but the underscore is a good convention as it is easy to read and less bulky visually.

Adding an underscore at the end of all lambdas that you would like deployed to nested stacks should do the trick. Feel free to check out this article - it is where those quotes are from and what we followed to split our resources! https://dev.to/slsbytheodo/override-the-resource-limit-of-aws-cloudformation-templates-with-serverless-framework-3bdh